# Crystal Reports 2013 User Groups/Security

Tags: crystal-reports

This is a few different questions.

First one is how do you delete a user group? I've seen the option for removing a group from another group, but I haven't been able to find an option for completely deleting the group.

Second is how do I set security so that users in a specific group can only view and run reports? So far, I've gone into User Security on the group, disabled inheriting from the parent group and folder, and set "View" and "View On Demand" in basic settings and "View objects" and "View objects that the user owns" in advanced. But regardless of what they have, either they can still move and delete reports or can't view anything at all depending on whether they're under the Administrators group.

Related to that last part of the second question, when the user group is a subgroup of Adminsitrators they can see all the tabs, but if I move them to the Everyone group, then they can't see anything when logged in when I set the Folders view on Configure CMC Tabs. Ideally, I'd like the users to be under a different group entirely for clarity, but then they can't seem to do anything, which definitely won't work.

Comment: Figured out the last point about deleting groups. It seems like since I'd given it customized security settings it wouldn't let me delete the group even after I'd removed it from all other groups. Once I reset the security to be inherited, it let me delete it fine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out.

For the first one, I couldn't delete the group because it had customized security settings. After resetting those to the default inheritance and removing it from all other groups, I was able to delete it fine.

For the folders and running the reports, the security has to be set on the folder structure, not on the user group.